# Using ' inside a c# string that launch a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm looking to do this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.');", true);
```

There is no way to formulate this french sentence without `'` :

```
'Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.'
```

Javascript fail because (probably) when encountering that caracter it expect it to be the end of the string.

I tried lots of thing like `\'` and `'''` but... no luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The JS part

What you want the client to receive is a JavaScript string that has a *value* of

```
Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.
```

To make a string that has that value in JavaScript, the JS string literal needs to be either:

<sub>1</sub>

```
"Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application."
^                                                       ^
```

or

<sub>2</sub>

```
'Vous n\'avez pas les droits d\'accès à cette application.'
       ^                      ^
```

This is because you either need to use different quote characters, or escape the character within the literal.

## The C# Part

What you want to send to the client is a *value* of the JS string literal (see 1 and 2 above).

To make a C# string that has either of those values you will need to escape the special characters within C#:

```
"alert(\"Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.\");"
       ^                                                        ^
```

or

```
@"alert(""Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application."");"
^       ^^                                                       ^^
```

or

```
"alert('Vous n\\'avez pas les droits d\\'accès à cette application.');"
              ^^                      ^^
```

or

```
@"alert('Vous n\'avez pas les droits d\'accès à cette application.');"
^              ^                      ^
```

---

This technique is called double escaping, and it's important to keep track of what *value* you need to have, and escape any special characters to achieve that value.

As you can see, this can be a bit tricky. There are utilities and classes that can help to automatically, and more importantly, correctly escape strings into whatever format/language/encoding you need them encoded in.

`JavaScriptSerializer` is a simple one that could be helpful in this case.

That all said, in my experience, double escaping issues are a red flag that you're not structuring your code properly. In this case, you have a line of code that's sending a message to the client, and you're embedding content within functionality. This will likely cause you headaches later when you go to try and change it and run into double escaping issues again. In this case, I would advocate using `[data-*]` attributes to send the data, and then to let `ScriptManager` call a function that reads the data and notifies the user properly.

Alternatively, an additional templating step can save some headaches in the future when you want to change the text or refactor:

```
var message = "Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.";
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var encodedMessage = jss.Serialize(message);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
  this,
  this.GetType(),
  Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
  string.Format("alert({0});", encodedMessage),
  true);
```

Comment: Minor mistake: `'Vous n\'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.'` should add `d\'accès`

Comment: @jHilscher, thanks for that. It makes the case for the later part of my answer even stronger. Use a tool to avoid user-error.

Answer (score 11):

You could try this one:

```
"alert(\"Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.\");"
```

Why this works?

- Τhe apostrophe character, ', should be included in double quotes. Otherwise, if you use apostrophes and place between them your string, the string can't be interpeted correctly by the JavaScript engine.
- We use the backslash character in order we define properly our string in C#, avoiding the double quotes, which is used, when we want to declare a string. Formally, this is called special characters escaping. Please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx).

For instance try to type this in the console of your browser (press F12 to go to the developer tools and the click on the console tab)

```
alert('Vous n'avez pas les droits d'accès à cette application.');
```

You will notice that 'Vous n' is interpreted as a string and of course you will; get the error that you have already mentioned in your answer. This may help you visualize the above.

Answer (score 2):

The output you want for your Javascript is this (properly escaped the `'`):

```
alert('Vous n\'avez pas les droits d\'accès à cette application.');
```

So you should place a `\` inside your string. Since `\` is the escape character, you have to escape it again in order to be the literal `\` character:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
    ( this
    , this.GetType()
    , Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    , "alert('Vous n\\'avez pas les droits d\\'accès à cette application.');"
    , true
    );
```